# HitMiss transformation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection, morphological-analysis

I'm performing Hit and Miss transformation on

[image]

with

[image]

but it's not producing nonzero detection result.

```
clear all,close all,clc
img=im2bw(imread('bw.jpg'));
B=im2bw(imread('B.jpg'));

find=B;
diff=imdilate(find,strel('square',3))-find;
sam=nonzeros(bwhitmiss(img,find,diff))
```

what's the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit or miss only works if the shape you want to detect in the matching image is **exactly the same** as the input query.  The `B` you are using is not the same shape or size as the `B` in the image you want to detect it in, and that's why you're not getting results.  You need to use something more sophisticated than morphology to detect the `B`.